# Count folders inside the folders

Tags: c#

I need to count all my folders in total inside my directory.
I need to know all the amount of the following Path/Folders/folders.
I have tried using directoryCount but that only returns the main folders and not my sub folders.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [EnumerateDirectories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383462.aspx)

```
Directory.EnumerateDirectories(dirPath, "*",
                    SearchOption.AllDirectories).Count();
```

Comment: I only need to know the two first sub folders, Of my main folder in C:/.

Comment: That is *not* what your question says... "I need to count all my folders in total inside my directory."

Comment: My question was edited for some reason.

Comment: The only thing edited in your question is the title. It cannot be done for c drive because of the access violations.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Directory.GetFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316.aspx) and [`Directory.GetDirectories`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143314.aspx) methods.

All files under mine `C:\Soner` path:

```
int files = Directory.GetFiles("C:\\Soner", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length;
//Prints 2766
```

All directories under mine `C:\Soner` path

```
int dirs = Directory.GetDirectories("C:\\Soner", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length;
//Prints 715
```

Here a screenshot;

[image]

Also be aware of [`Directory.EnumerateDirectories`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383462.aspx) method because

> The EnumerateDirectories and GetDirectories methods differ as follows:
>   When you use EnumerateDirectories, you can start enumerating the
>   collection of names before the whole collection is returned; when you
>   use GetDirectories, you must wait for the whole array of names to be
>   returned before you can access the array. Therefore, when you are
>   working with many files and directories, EnumerateDirectories can be
>   more efficient.

```
var count = from dr in
            Directory.EnumerateDirectories("C:\\Soner", "*",SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            select dr;
```

After your edit:

> I only need to know the two first sub folders, Of my main folder in
>   C:/.

You can use;

```
string[] subdir = Directory.GetDirectories("C:\\", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
Console.WriteLine(subdir[0]); // Your first subfolder under your C:\
Console.WriteLine(subdir[1]); // Your second subfolder under your C:\
```

**But be careful**. This code throws exception called *"Acces path is denied"* because you iterating all your folders in your `C:\` drive and some of folders are protected by operating system.

Comment: Didnt it throw any exception for you? I've tried this on my machine and there is some `access denied` exception.

Comment: @KingKing If you tried it under your `C:` drives, since some of folders are protected by operating system, you can get an exception of course.

Comment: That means this method won't work for some cases (even in other drives which have some system folder).

Comment: BTW, the `Length` property should be used instead of `Count()` static method which may iterate the string array one more time.

Comment: I only need to know the two first sub folders, Of my main folder in C:/.

Comment: @IngelaTörner Updated my answer. Take a look.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
public int NumOfDirs(string path)
    {
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(path);
        DirectoryInfo[] allDirs = dir.GetDirectories("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        return allDirs.Length;
    }
```

But you will need to make sure you have access to all of the sub directories or else you will get an exception.